# operator overloading for standard type; double % double

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Im hoping to be able to overload the % operator, or really any of them, to do something particular between two double amounts.

I'm attempting to do this because I need do a check on the value obtained in an operation like the following but I don't want to use space to store it to then do the checks. My ideal code would be:

```
double& operator% (const double& left, const doouble right){
    while(left >= right){
        left -= right;
    
    return left;
}

int main(){
    (double)s1 / 30269.0 + (double)s2 / 30307.0 + (double)s3 / 30323.0 % 1;
}                                                                      ^
                                                                       ^
```

Comment: No, you can't overload operators for in-built types. Which is a good thing, otherwise you could never be sure what `1 + 2` means.

Comment: You can make your own [user defined infix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356668/user-defined-infix-operators), but please don't do that.  Just make a regular freestanding function that does what you want; operator overloading is not the C++ idiomatic way to go for these kinds of things.

Comment: I understand the concerns and all I'm trying to do is add functionality to something cpp is missing. This is really the module operation but for non-ints. It's why I'm hoping to keep the same symbol.