# Equivalent Operator to Pythons //?

Tags: python, c++

I was wondering if there is an operator in C++ that does the same thing as // operator in Python (floor division)?

Comment: `/` does the thing given you typecast the result into `int`.

Comment: thanks. So typecast to int is like a floor function?

Comment: @Cplusplusbeginner: Yes, as long as you remember that all floating points are quasi-unpredictable, so it may floor to a number other than the one you expected

Comment: While `floor` will convert the floating point to 0, `int` typecasting will drop off the floating points altogether.

Comment: You could make a `x = y /floor/ z;` using [infix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356668/4641116) technique.  Not recommended, though.  I suggest `x = std::floor(y / z);` as more idiomatic C++.

Comment: Casting to `int` is a bad suggestion. It shall result in value truncation if the result can't be represented within `int`.

Answer (score 1):

IN PYTHON

You can use `int(a/b)` to get the same result as `a//b`.

Basically `//` refers to the floor decision and it is exactly the same if we convert a floating-point to an integer by typecasting.

You can even import math and find the floor of a floating-point number.

```
import math

math.floor(a/b)
```

FOR C++

Simply divide the variable with the declaration of result as int datatype.

```
int result = a/b;
```

or you can use a floor operator

```
#include <math.h>    
using namespace std;

void main(){
    std::floor(a/b);
}
```

Comment: added c++ solution as well as python solution

Comment: For `int result = a/b` , What if `a/b` can't be accommodated in an `int`?

Comment: if the value is too large then we can use `long long int` datatype.

Comment: This is an awful answer, and it's a shame it is upvoted, at least when it comes to C++ part.

Answer (score 0):

If `lhs` and `rhs` are two integers (`short`, `int`, `unsigned long`, ...), `lhs / rhs` is the result of the integer division of those two values. Its type follows standard [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

If either `lhs` or `rhs` is a floating point, you'd need [`std::floor(lhs / rhs)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor). Alternatives are [`std::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) and [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).