# Is there a way to assign an operator to a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a class **Foo** with **+** and **-** operators defined:

```
class Foo
{
    .
    .
    .
}
Foo& operator+(const Foo& f1, const Foo&f2)
{
    .
    .
    .
}

Foo& operator-(const Foo& f1, const Foo&f2)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there a syntax in C++ that allows me to assign one of its operators to a variable and use that operation in an expression?

Something like the following:

```
Operator o = positive ? operator+ : operator-;
.
.
.
Foo f1{...};
Foo f2{...};
Foo result = f1 o f2;
```

Comment: You can assign functions to variables that are _function pointers_.

Comment: Nope. You can go with `o(f1, f2);`, but you can't make a custom operator in C++, only overload existing ones.

Comment: [Note that some operators cannot be overloaded](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#overloadable-opers).

Comment: No, you can't, and it's Good Thing because such code would be completely unmaintainable.

Comment: There is this almost similar syntax : `o(f1,f2)` which we all use (preferably with `o` being a more descriptive function name). Don't try to outsmart yourself (and all others reading your code) with trying to invent new syntax.

Comment: You could have [user defined infix operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356668/4641116), and then assign the one you want with `Operator op = positive ? add : sub;` and call it with `Foo result = f1 <op> f2;`.  But listen to Pepijn and avoid these kinds of shenanigans!

Comment: Returning a non-const reference is highly unusual here. Not related to your question, just consider returning a `const` reference or just`Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create a new operator in C++. While it is possible to have operators for custom classes like your

```
Foo& operator-(const Foo& f1, const Foo&f2);
```

it is not possible to have a new operator like `o` and use it like `f1 o f2`.

---

However you can have a function pointer to your operator and use it afterwards. This could be achieved with the following line of code:

```
auto op = true ? operator+ : operator-;
```

But what happens if you have e.g. a second class `Bar` with an overloaded `operator+`? Then this won't work since the compiler will have trouble to select the right operator with the right type. To work around this you could cast each operator to its type like the following to give the compiler a hint:

```
using FooOp = Foo&(*)(const Foo&, const Foo&);
FooOp op = true ? static_cast<FooOp>(operator+) : static_cast<FooOp>(operator-);
```

Now you can call your `op` like a normal function:

```
Foo f1, f2;
Foo result = op(f1, f2);
```

---

This achieves the same results as what you intended, but you still don't have your "operator" `o`. So why even bother with this and not just use a conditional assignment to `result`.

```
result = true ? (f1 + f2) : (f1 - f2);
```

This is probably easier to read and understand than the whole new operator or function pointer mess.

Comment: "why even bother" — the same question and answer as for pointers. Why bother making a pointer when you can use the object itself?